# Prevent Gson from escaping Unicode symbols

Tags: java, unicode, gson

I have `Map<String, String>` which later I want to serialize to JSON using Gson. Some of keys of this map contain Unicode characters like `\uf177` etc. The problem appears when I try to serialize such a map to JSON, let's say I have `Map<String, String>` containing:

```
"TEST_KEY" -> "\uf177"
```

then, when serialized using Gson, I have:

```
{
    "TEST_KEY": "\\uf177"
}
```

Which is not what I want, I want these Unicode symbols to be as they are when serialized. Is there a way to achieve this? Would appreciate any help,

**UPDATE**

Code which produces the issue:

```
       projectI18nFileContent = commentsRemover.transform(projectI18nFileContent);

        //find json map which represents translations
        Matcher fullTranslationsMapMatcher = translationsMapSerializedToJsonPattern.matcher(projectI18nFileContent);

        if (!fullTranslationsMapMatcher.find()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(format("%s \n does not contain valid translations json map", projectI18nFileContent));
        }

        String translationsMapSerializedToJson = fullTranslationsMapMatcher.group();
        String newTranslationsMapSerializedToJson = gson.toJson(newTranslations);

        //replace old json translations map with a new
        return projectI18nFileContent.replace(translationsMapSerializedToJson, newTranslationsMapSerializedToJson);
```

This piece of code is dedicated to change content of i18n file for javascript project, this is the reason why unicode should not be escaped (otherwise it's just resolved not correctly)

Thanks,
Cheers

Comment: Yes: if it's the 6-character string, then the correct way to write it is "\\uf177". So gson's behaviour is normal.

Comment: Can you show a little bit more code? It seems you have a string with the litteral characters `\uf177` in it rather than whatever Unicode character that represents.

Comment: @JeremyP added a bit more code, thanks!

Comment: Mike Adamenko's solution is correct as far as it goes. Instead of the string you are serialising containing a Unicode character, it actually contains the literal sequence `\ u f 1 7 7`. If that's what you want, Mike's answer is correct and you should accept it (when the JSON string is deserialised, the extra backslash will be removed). If that is not what you want, you need to look to the source of the string which is giving you an escape sequence instead of the Unicode character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Json spec](http://json.org/) the backslashes must to be escaped.

So you shouldn't try to prevent this. It's correct behavior.

Comment: The Java compiler should have translated the `\uF177` into the character it represents so this is not really the right answer.

Comment: @JeremyP did you read Json spec from the link ? especially this part http://json.org/string.gif

Comment: `\uf177` is a *single* Unicode code character. It should have gone through the top path in your diagram. Whenever the Java compiler sees the sequence `\uXXXX` where XXXX is a hex string, it replaces that six character sequence with the single Unicode character it represents.

Comment: No, the top path is any Unicode character  except " or \ or  control-character. So because \uXXXX contains \ it will be escaped.

Comment: There is no \ in `\uf177` if it appears in a Java source file because the first thing the compiler does is [turn it into the unicode character it represents](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.2). The problem of the question is that the input string unexpectedly contains the literal sequence `\uf177` instead of the Unicode character.

Comment: he has "\uf177"  as string in his Map. So the compiler compiles it just as simple string.

Comment: It is correct behavior in most scenarios. Sometimes people need what they need and just want to know how to get there. gson adding a backslash is great for when converting the resulting json back into a POJO but that might be of no concern to the OP.